# Simpler way to send data to mysql with flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Abstract:
My problem: I think my code a bit verbose.
What I want: Simplify my code in order to make it easier to read and execute.
What I use: Python/Flask/MySql

I built a simple login and register site with Flask. However I think one of my functions in a route is a bit verbose.

First I created the route:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Second, I created a function called register.

```
def register():
```

This function must return a html page in the end:

```
return render_template('register.html', msg=msg)
```

Inside this function I made an empty variable to store my error messages:

```
msg = ''
```

Finally, inside my function I put a conditional to send the caught data from the form and send them to my MySql DataBase:

```
if request.method=='POST' and 'nome' in request.form and 'cpf' in request.form and 'cep' in request.form and 'whatsapp' in request.form and 'aniversario' in request.form and 'senha' in request.form:
        nome = request.form['nome']
        cpf = request.form['cpf']
        cep = request.form['cep']
        whatsapp = request.form['whatsapp']
        aniversario = request.form['aniversario']
        senha = request.form['senha']
        data = [datetime.datetime.today()]

        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE cpf=%s', (cpf,))
        account = cursor.fetchone()

        if account:
            msg = 'Cadastro já existe!'
        elif re.match(r'[[A-Z][a-z]+([ ][A-Z][a-z]+)*]', nome):
            msg = 'O nome deve conter apenas caracteres latinos'
        elif not re.match(r'[\d]', cpf):
            msg = 'O CPF deve conter 11 algarismos'
        elif not re.match(r'[0-9]', cep):
            msg = 'O CEP deve conter 8 algarismos'
        elif not re.match(r'[0-9]', whatsapp):
            msg = 'O Whatsapp deve conter 11 algarismos'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO cadastro VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (nome, cpf, cep, whatsapp, aniversario, senha, data,))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'Cadastro feito com sucesso!'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        msg = 'Preencha todo cadastro!'
```

Well, I would like to simplify my nested conditional where I set the regex rules to accept the data. I Want to accept just the names, ids, streets and whatsapps which match to the regex patterns above. And mainly just to accept the form if the id is unique. If there is another one equal id, it mustn't accept the data. How could I do that in a simpler way? How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

`if request.method=='POST' and set(['nome','cpf','cep','whatsapp','aniversario','senha']).issubset(request.form):`

That might help make the code less "verbose", assuming request.form is a list.

You could also consider using and ORM, such as SQLAlchemy. It makes the database interaction more pythonic (You won't have to write in SQL).

As far as making sure the id is unique, it looks like your solution is straight forward. In my Flask project (where I user SQLAlchemy) I'd have done this:

```
account = cadastro.query.filter_by(crf=crf).first()
if account:
    # code
```